# OpenCV running optical flow on particular rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I am using OpenCV's Optical Flow module. I understand the examples in the documentation but those take the entire image and then get the optical flow over the image.

I only want to pass it over some parts of an image. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how do I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` will be the optical flow function you need. Before you make that function call, you will have to create an image mask. I did a similar project, but in C++, though I can outline the steps for you:

- Create an empty matrix with same width and height of your images
- Using the points from your ROI, create a shape out of it (I did mine using `cv2.fillPoly()`) and fill the inside of the shape with white *(Your image mask should only be comprised of black and white color)*
- If you are planning on using corners as features, then call `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` and pass in the mask you've made as one of its arguments.
- If you're using the Feature2D module to detect features, you can use the same mask to only extract the features in that masked area.
- By this step, you should now have a collection of features/points that are only within the bounds of the shape! Call the optical flow function and then process the results.

I hope that helps.